# specflow gives error after adding more string parameters

Tags: c#, specflow

Spec flow was working fine. I added some more string parameters in one of the `Given` statement and suddenly I start getting  this error

```
Class Initialization method AutomatedRediTests.RediFeature.FeatureSetup threw exception. BoDi.ObjectContainerException: BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved: System.String.


at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath) in W:\SpecFlow\BoDi\BoDi\BoDi.cs:line 772
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name) in W:\SpecFlow\BoDi\BoDi\BoDi.cs:line 698
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name) in W:\SpecFlow\BoDi\BoDi\BoDi.cs:line 680
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer container) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestObjectResolver.cs:line 11
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ResolveArgument(IObjectContainer container, IBindingParameter parameter) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 285
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<ResolveArguments>b__0(IBindingParameter p) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 273
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ResolveArguments(IHookBinding hookBinding, IObjectContainer currentContainer) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 273
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 242
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 234
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnTestRunStart() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 69
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnTestRunStart() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunner.cs:line 29
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.InitializeBindingRegistry(ITestRunner testRunner) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunnerManager.cs:line 73
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.CreateTestRunner(Int32 threadId) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunnerManager.cs:line 60
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunnerWithoutExceptionHandling(Int32 threadId) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunnerManager.cs:line 147
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Int32 threadId) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunnerManager.cs:line 134
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Assembly testAssembly, Nullable`1 managedThreadId) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunnerManager.cs:line 224
```

How do I go about resolving this error? It asks to resolve  `System.String`

**EDIT:**

looks like in specflow bindings I have a line `someMachine abc = SomeControl.BeforeTestRun();` and I needed it to change so it passes a string like `someMachine abc = SomeControl.BeforeTestRun("someString");` . When I pass this string , I get this error. No matter if I write the line inside a step definition method or just inside the class.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Add new strings one at a time until you find which is causing the issue.

Comment: @jdweng And If I find that string , how do I resolve? I think I know which string is that

Comment: I suspect you are trying to convert a structure to a string and there is no method that does the conversion.  You would need to create code to convert the structure to a string.  Often I use String Join to take an array object and make it a single string.

Comment: @jdweng I edited above to provide more information. Is there a way to do what I edited above?

Comment: I usually create a custom class that inherits the standard control.  So If you have a button I create a class MyButton : Button  and then in the class have a method ToString().

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure if I understand. So , `SomeControl` is a class that inherits another `ControlClass` that was given in a custom framework. `BeforeTestRun` method is annotated `[BeforeTestRun]` in that `ControlClass` . I am not understanding why passing a string invokes the error. Does it have to do something with passing to this `[BeforeTestRun]` annotated method?

Comment: Please post the method implementing the `Given` step.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error, if you have a string parameter in the constructor of a class that you get via context injection.

Comment: how do I go about resolving it? As I described above in edit and comment,  I need to pass parameter in `[BeforeTestRun]` annotated method. I am not using context injection here. So you are saying , I will get this error even if I  use proper context injection as described [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection)

Comment: Please add the whole code of the class that makes problems. Without it, I can't say anything concrete.

Comment: @ Andreas Willich , I am not able to post the whole code currently but I am able to achieve what I was doing by passing static properties from one class to another and the reading property in `[BeforeTestRun]` instead of having variable as parameter. But for more complex scenarios context injection would be the way to go. Is there a general workaround of the issue that you mentioned ?

Comment: The workaround is to encapsulate the string in your own type.